# How can I start programming with DirectX 11 on Windows 7 (in 2018)?

Tags: directx

I have installed Visual Studio Community 2017 on Windows 7. And I have installed Windows 10 SDK (Because I read that DirectX SDK was integrated to Windows 10 SDK).

I would like to start game programming with DirectX 11 instead of DirectX 12, to create a PC game. (Not an app)

But I could not find any tutorial for this environment, do I need to upgrade to Windows 10?

If so, is there any step-by-step tutorial for DirectX 11 on Windows 10?

Comment: Better use an existing engine to develop games. There's Unreal Engine, CryEngine etc for doing so. Here are some DirectX 11 tutorials: http://www.rastertek.com/tutdx11.html

Comment: I found sample codes at https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Direct3D-Tutorial-Win32-829979ef . After they are converted on Visual Studio 2017, they run well. But I am not sure DirectX 12 is useful to create a PC game as well (Not only for UWP?). Thanks anyway for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are a ton of tutorials, books, and other materials available for using DirectX 11 on Windows 7. The main issue is that many of them rely on the legacy DirectX SDK as you note. This can be worked around easily enough, but it can be confusing to people new to the platform.

If you are looking for C++ code tutorials that use DirectX 11, are compatible with Windows 7 SP1, and don't use the legacy DirectX SDK (with [one exception](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/04/02/xaudio2-and-windows-8/) due to XAudio2.8+ lack of support for Windows 7), see [DirectX Tool Kit for DX11](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started).

Also, the most current version of that Direct3D 11 tutorial project you reference can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples/tree/master/Direct3D11Tutorials).

You can also find some basic DirectX 11 and DirectX 12 tutorials at [Xbox-ATG-Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples/tree/master/PCSamples/IntroGraphics).

> See [Living without D3DX](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/08/20/living-without-d3dx/) for specific information on replacements for legacy D3DX11.

*Even if you are interested in using DirectX 12 eventually, I strongly recommend learning DirectX 11 first. The APIs are quite different in detail, but all the logical underpinnings are the same and DirectX 11 is a lot more forgiving for newcomers.*